# Short, undistracting prefix vs. underscore convention

Tags: python, naming-conventions, naming

Grouping dictionary keys by a prefix is useful when exploring its structure. However, what to do with keys that cannot be easily grouped / are miscellaneous?

```
mydict = {'_id': '',
          '_nick': '',
          '_address': '',

          'status_destination': '',
          'status_file': '',
          'status_object': '',

          'objective_value': '',
          'objective_result': '',}
```

Prefix underscore is shorter than something arbitrary like misc. But, underscore has a certain meaning in python. Dictionary keys are object names and as such, they shall not be prefixed by underscore according to PEP-8.

What could be used instead that is not distractive? Ordered dictionary does not always work since misc keys can be entered at various times.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

[What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a matter of preference, but my suggestions are:

1. use `CamelCase` for key name and `single_underscore` as delimiter to group prefix. No underscore means miscellaneous.
2. use `single_underscores` for key name and `double__underscore` as delimiter to group prefix. Note that PEP-8 does only mention double *leading* or *trailing* underscores, so a key like `status__destination` is according to PEP-8.

Comment: If there is no underscore, the miscellaneous keys will be all over the place... The second suggestion implies using smth like misc_key which is quite heavy, more so if dictionary itself is called misc :-).